# Android - Image files in external storage are not included in ContentResolver results

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, android-external-storage

I have an application that writes jpg image files to a directory structure in the app's external storage.
I was planning to use `ContentResolver` to scan through the directory structure so I can search both a specific folder or all folders. However, the ContentResolver query I wrote does not return any of the files written by the app (it does return other files in the phone though).
Here is the code:

```
    // Create Content Resolver
    ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
    // List of fields we want to include in the query
    String[] projection = new String[] { BaseColumns._ID,
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE };
    // Run the query and return a crusor
    cursor = resolver.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    // URI = Uniform Resource Identifier
            projection, // which fields
            null , // selection criteria
            null, // selection arguments
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE + " DESC"); 

    if ((cursor != null) && (cursor.moveToFirst()))
    {
        do // loop through the items in the list of results, using the cursor
        {
            long id = cursor.getLong(0); 
            String name = cursor.getString(1);
            long size = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE));
            Log.i(TAG, "Image: id = " + id + "  name = " + name
                    + "  size = " + size);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    } else {
        Log.w(TAG, "System media store is empty.");
    }
```

I tried restarting the phone (so the ContentProvider will be updated), I tried on several different devices and emulators. Nothing helped.

What am I doing wrong?

While we are at it, could you please guide me how to filter the results by the directory name (e.g. show only the files in a specific sub-directory, or all the files under the app's external storage directory).

Thank you!

Yossi

Comment: `the app's external storage. `. Please explain what that is exactly. Which path? You do not mean phone's external storage?

Comment: `resolver` ? Please show how you declare and instantiate that.

Comment: I have update the code above to include the declaration and instantiation  of resolver

Comment: As for the "external storage" - I'm writing the image (using OpenCV) to a sub-folder of context.getExternalFilesDir(null) .
I can list and view the images using a FileManager app, but the ContentResolver does list them.

Comment: Maybe it's because it is private external app memory that the MediaStore is not scanning it. Or is there somewhere in the ../Android/ directory a `.nomedia` file who prevents scanning by the MediaStore? Can you test try with just using an external non app specific directory ? (outside that Android directory).